iptables for route all packet except some process
My tailscaled magisk module run in userspace mode, in order to proxy traffict to localsocks5 on port 1099 I'm using hev-socks5-tunnel.
Using iptables to mark packet the connection going to 100.64.0.0/10 must using tailscale0.
# Add route which subnet do you want to access it directly and dont forget to add also in tailscaled.tun.down
ip route add 100.64.0.0/10 dev tailscale0 metric 1

# Set iptables rules to mark packets
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d 100.64.0.0/10 -j MARK --set-mark 1099

# Add IP rule
ip rule add fwmark 1099 table 1099
ip rule add fwmark 1099 lookup 1099

# Add default route for marked traffic
ip route add default dev tailscale0 table 1099 metric 1

You can check at here https://github.com/anasfanani/Magisk-Tailscaled/blob/main/tailscale/scripts/tailscaled.tun.up and https://github.com/anasfanani/Magisk-Tailscaled/blob/main/tailscale/scripts/tailscaled.tun.down
This is my best configuration for now, only work for IP 100.64.0.0/10.
What I need is routing all packet in android using the tailscale0, If VPN or WiFi is activated, packet redirection will still work properly, except connection for tailscaled and tailscale binary still using default connection android.
